# Avoid launching when setting variable to path to applet

Tags: applescript

If I set a variable in AppleScript to the path to an AppleScript applet or droplet, the applet or droplet is launched and the `run()` handler is executed. For example, I have

```
set thePath to path to application "HS Extract"
```

and this launches the droplet "HS Extract". I have also tried setting a variable to the application as alias and then setting a variable to the path to the alias and a few other possibilities that all failed.

How can I set a variable to the path to a droplet or applet without launching that droplet or applet?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to find things is using mdfind from the shell and metadata properties. This is like doing a spotlight search and this method shouldn't launch any applications.

For example applications have the kMDItemContentType property of com.apple.application-bundle. If we combine this with the name of an application we can create something like the following to get a posix path and then convert it into an alias.

```
set appDisplayName to "HS Extract"
set posixPath to item 1 of paragraphs of (do shell script "mdfind \"kMDItemContentType == 'com.apple.application-bundle' && kMDItemDisplayName == " & quoted form of appDisplayName & "\"")
set thePath to (POSIX file posixPath) as alias
```

NOTE: you mention the bundle id is common in your comment to jackjr300's post. The bundle identifier has the kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier metadata property. So if the combination of kMDItemContentType and kMDItemDisplayName doesn't work (as in my example code) then you can try kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier and kMDItemDisplayName instead.

Comment: This won't work if Spotlight is turned off in the Preferences panel, but I give you a vote for the ingenuity. If nothing else works, I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

To not open an application : use the **Finder** to get the path, this need the bundle identifier of the application.

```
set bundlId to id of application "HS Extract"
tell application "Finder" to set thePath to (application file id bundlId) as alias
```

---

Or you can use a **NSWorkspace** method to get the path, this doesn't need an identifier

```
do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c 'from AppKit import NSWorkspace; print NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().fullPathForApplication_(\"HS Extract\")'"
set thePath to the result as POSIX file as alias
```

Comment: It is an applet or droplet, which has a standard identifier, which is the same for all applets or droplets. I have been thinking of changing the bundle identifier, but that solution isn't ideal.

Comment: On **Yosemite** and **Mavericks**, the script editor doesn’t use a generic identifier. When I save a droplet named "HS Extract", the identifier is **"com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.HS-Extract"**.  And you can change it directly in the script editor.

Comment: I updated the answer with another method without  identifier.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting it as a string, then, if you need to launch it, coercing to alias.

```
Set thePath to (choose file as string)
--gives you path string
```

you can use that string in a variable, but use

```
alias thePath
```

if you need to.

Comment: This is one reason why I generally like to use strings to store things like paths, then use Mac's alias if I really need to.

Comment: I can´t use `choose file`.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use "choose file" in your script, I'm giving you a way to get a path you can use and coerce it to a string.`

Comment: And I guess I should've asked, why not just use a string?

Comment: It doesn´t matter whether I use an alias or a string. The point is that the applet is launched and I don´t want that.

Comment: Hm. Well, if I use a string it doesn't launch. If I use the code you posted, it does. Perhaps there is more in your code that may be launching it?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @jackjr300's answer, but if this script is for private use, a `property` seems to work:

```
property appPath : path to application "HS Extract"
display dialog appPath as string
```

The application is only launched when the script is compiled. Note that the property is an [alias](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28).

The script will track the original `HS Extract`, even if it's later renamed to something else.

Comment: This is a bad solution, because it also launches when the script runs on the user's computer for the first time.

Comment: If the script will be leaving your machine, use @jackjr300's answer.